# jQuery: Accessing error code if image fails to load

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, error-handling

I have a page where users can add images (browse for files, drag/drop or copy/paste) from their filesystem, clipboard, or external websites. If an image fails to load, I'd like to let the user know why. For example, `404 (resource not found)` or `403 (Forbidden)` - users may want to try different things depending on why the image failed to load.

I'm dealing with failure using the following code:

```
var image=$('<img>').appendTo(container);
image.error(function(e){/* error handling code*/});
image.attr('src','example.jpg');
```

I can't figure out how to access the particular error code that led to failure. If I open developer tools (chrome), the error message gets displayed there... how can I access that same message in my code?

Comment: @JasonP my guess is he wants to see 404 or 403 with the text status. I can't seem to find that inside the event object.

Comment: @JasonP I get the error callback to trigger just fine; the question is, how can I access the status code?

Answer (score -1):

You can try this.

```
var img = $.get("/img/example.jpg");
var statusCode = img.status,
statusText = img.statusText;
```